# Upgrade 2.5 to 3.5 SQL error

Tags: mysql, upgrade

I've recently upgraded a test site on 2.5.8 to 3.5.1.

Before the upgrade all components were updated or disabled if not useable in 3.5.1. From here I used the Joomla Upgrade to get it to the latest version and had no issue with the backend of the website.

The front end however gives the following:

```
Unknown column 'ordering' in 'order clause' SQL=SELECT m.* FROM #__menu AS m WHERE menutype='mainmenu' AND published = 1 AND access IN (1,1,2,6) ORDER BY ordering
```

Disabling the main menu and adding a new one still seems to give the error and I can't find Ordering or Order Clause within the database (It may be there, I just can't seem to find it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to try and do. In your Joomla back-end, go to:

> Extensions >> Manage >> Database

If a notification appears saying there are some database structure errors, click the "**Fix**" button.

Once done or if there's nothing to fix, go to

> Menus >> Main Menu >> Rebuild

If you have more than just 1 menu being used on your website, then try also rebuilding those menus too.

#### Update:

Ok having looked through the SQL changes from 2.5 to 3.x, the `ordering` column was dropped in Joomla 3.0.0:

```
ALTER TABLE `#__menu` DROP COLUMN `ordering`;
```

So for some reason, your system is still trying to order by this column so perhaps the update wasn't 100% successful. Try downloading a fresh copy of Joomla 3.5.1, extract ONLY the directories from the root (e.g `modules`, `plugins`, `administrator`, etc) and upload them to your server.

I do hope you took a backup of your Joomla 3.5 site before the update

Comment: Just tired both of these but same result.

Comment: @leemurphy - see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Check HTML folder in your template and check menu overrides. May be some one hardcoded 'ordering' in it.

Comment: Using the gantry and basic joomla theme, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Well, my best suggestion then is to copy site to local machine and go trough with total commander search text in files "menutype='mainmenu'" - so you will end up with list of files - check them and you'll find the issue.